# Visualising geo data on a map

Tags: video, software-recommendation

Hi I have an interesting task I want to achieve. I currently manage a website that acts as a tracking system for a popular piece of flight simulation software. Currently we take a dump of the lat/lon and other data of everybody flying every 5 minutes. This has been done constantly for the past two years. There is close to a million records now in the database.

What I would really like to produce is a video of the world showing these lines being drawn in a sped-up fashion however this isn't really my area and I can't think of the best way I could go about this in such a programatic fashion. I've seen similar types of videos done before but has anyone got any ideas of what routes I could go down to make this visualisation?

Thanks,
Rory

Comment: I just tried to visualise all the data at once in Google Earth with some interesting results: http://cl.ly/image/2b0x1N09270X http://cl.ly/image/3G233e0m3N3C now I just need to work out how I can make more use of this.

Comment: Unless you want to make some really fancy animations I would merge this question with https://gis.stackexchange.com/ if thats ok for you.
Like quade said this is would be possible with After Effects with a lot of knowledge about After Effects and some After Effects scripting skills.
I don't think you want to go down that road but instead use software made for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is probably less of a question for video production people as much as it is for Geographic Information Systems (GIS) people.

[GIS Forum on Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com)

While you might be able to find an After Effects (AE) wizard who knows some scripting tricks to make this happen, my guess is more folks over in a GIS forum know how to do this in something like ArcGIS.

Additionally, laying out a million records is going to be an awful lot to ask of a program like AE or Motion, while that amount of detail is pretty much what ArcGIS exists to deal with.

My guess is if this is a one-shot project, you could probably hire some college student to turn it around for you.  If it's going to be something on-going and constantly updated for your web site with a million plus data points, that might be also do-able, but a much bigger programming issue.

Comment: There will be commercial and open source solutions to this , thanks for including the link to GIS-SE all GIS related questions welcome.  @Rory can ask there